# Setter overloading in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, setter

When trying to define a setter that accepts a parameter type that can be used to construct a property, thusly:

```
class Buffer(buf: String) {}

class Foo {
    var buffer: Buffer? = null
        set(value: String) {
            field = Buffer(value)
        }
}
```

I get the error message:

> Setter parameter type must be equal to the type of the property

So what's meant to be the Kotlin way of doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of Kotlin 1.1 it is not possible to overload property setters. The feature request is tracked here:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-4075

Currently, you would have to define a `buffer` extension function on `String`:

```
val String.buffer : Buffer
    get() = Buffer(this)
```

and set the value with

```
Foo().buffer = "123".buffer
```