# Kotlin: single property with multiple setters of different types

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to build a class that has a property of `LocalDate` type which has setters that accept different types: `LocalDate` or `String`. In case of `LocalDate`, the value gets assigned directly, in case of `String`, it gets parsed and then assigned.
In Java, I just need to implement two overloaded setters handling both of above mentioned cases. But I have no idea how to handle that in Kotlin. I have tried this:

```
class SomeExampleClass(var _date: LocalDate) {
    var date = _date
        set(value) {
            when(value) {
                is LocalDate -> value
                is String -> LocalDate.parse(value)
            }
        }
}
```

It doesn't compile. How can I resolve such a problem?

Comment: You want to be able to set it after construction with either, or construct it with either?

Comment: String: set after (this is a case when data is transferred from JSP file to Spring controller).
LocalDate: construct or set after

Comment: Setter overload is not supported at this moment. You may refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43086327/setter-overloading-in-kotlin) or this [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-4075).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some time I returned to the problem of overloaded setters and developed the following solution:

```
class A(_date: LocalDate) {
    var date: Any = _date
        set(value) {
            field = helperSet(value)
        }
        get() = field as LocalDate

    private fun <T> helperSet(t: T) = when (t) {
        is LocalDate -> t
        is String -> LocalDate.parse(t)
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
    }
}
```

Comment: It's kind of nice, but too bad all the verification you get is runtime.

Comment: It is sad to see that Kotlin doesn't support this out of the box..

Answer (score 3):

So if you just want to construct it (via `constructor`), just create a [secondary constructor](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#secondary-constructors)

```
SomeExampleClass(LocalDate.MAX)
SomeExampleClass("2007-12-03")

class SomeExampleClass(var _date: LocalDate) {
    constructor(_date: String) : this(LocalDate.parse(_date))
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work in case of real not simplified code http://clip2net.com/s/3NE0Vra

Comment: But I guess the problem in the screenshot has nothing to do with this issue, hasn't it?

Comment: The actual problem was resolved by means of creating a DTO class to transfer data with string type date and time from JSP to Spring controller and then converting it to the class with LocalDate/LocalTime format.